# How tell when a hidden field is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some javascript I want to run when a hidden field is changed (via javascript) Is there any way to do this? (or anyway at all to have a field that is not "visible" in asp mvc that I can get a change event on)

**NOTE:** I have confirmed that it is not the fact that the field that is hidden that is the problem, but the fact the field is updated with javascript! The change event does not fire when I update a field with javascript.

**Edited**

To Clarify this works:

```
//set up change event
$('#154').change(function() {
ScoringDerivation(154, 6,162,165);;                                                             
                        });

<select id="154" name="154"><option value="">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
<option value="6001">Good</option>
<option value="6002">Average</option>
<option value="6003">Poor</option>
<option selected="selected" value="6004">No Match</option>
</select>
```

But this does not:

```
//set up change event
$('#165').change(function() {
    DerivationAdd3(165,166,167,226);; 
});


<input id="165" name="165" type="hidden" value="0" /><label id="165Label" name="165Label">0</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to do the checking.

```
$('#FieldId').change( function() { alert(9); })
```

it could be onchange or changed.  untested but i use similar.

google jQuery;

actually, here is the source you need i think.  [change()-jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: ok, this is what I have tried... does not work. (have edited my post above)

Comment: cool, so basically the solution is that after I update a field with javascript, I need to run the .change() command...

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Javascript to change the hidden field, why not just have that Javascript call the desired onchange function?

Comment: because I am running a $.GetJSON command, and the onchange function gets fired before the results come in ;(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and couldn't fire the change event since I can't modify the code that's actually setting the field. So here's what I did:

```
var file = $("#hidden_field_id");
var previous_value = file.attr("defaultValue");
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(previous_value != file.val()){
    fire_change_event(previous_value, file.val());
    previous_value = file.val();
    }
}, 50);
$(window).unload(function(){clearInterval(interval);});
```

This seemed to work in the 3 minutes of testing I did;)